# Generate a key pair in "node-forge" using "exponent", "modulus" and "maxdigits"

Tags: cryptography, cryptojs, forge

I'm using "node-forge" to generate a publicKey to use with my AES symmetric key but I don't know how to use the data provided by my  backend to create this publicKey. Currently, I receive from an authentication api the following:

> e: "10001"
>   n:"c7c5dd235568711a943ebbdacac890ca2cf12c1ab539f77726e8874d2ab4220cf06369358b5eff0425fb17d4f696f741cf04c5ea874415e7f67d118a2e763e641e8675b8f42e9277b3f70f14e4de23fe16f51abdc427490f47e4b28ae3e5eb3563ba797fe90f9b70ba878646b1b297c52ba735827682b67309d38b423e31b50b"
>   maxdigits: "131"

Where "e" is my exponent, "n" is my module and "maxdigits" is the length my BigIntegers are supposed to have.

But when I try something like this:

```
const keys = forge.pki.rsa.generateKeyPair({ e: res.e, n: res.n });
```

My backend returns an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide full details about the error. Also, your 1024-bit modulus means your bigints will have 1024 bits or 309 base 10 digits. I don't where maxdigits=131 comes from.

Comment: @JamesKPolk In bytes it is 128 + 3, i.e. the size of the modulus and exponent size. It could also be the OCTET STRING size of the modulus. Those make some kind of sense, but I'm not sure if it is one of these two options (and it wouldn't explain the `digits` part of the element name).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: Ah, thanks, that makes much more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`forge.pki.rsa.generateKeyPair` is the wrong method in this context. `forge.pki.rsa.generateKeyPair` creates a *new* key pair with *random* modulus. The first parameter specifies the modulus/key size in bits, the second the exponent ([[1]](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge#rsa) and [[2]](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/master/lib/rsa.js)):

```
// var forge = require('node-forge'); // in nodejs-context
var pki = forge.pki;
var rsa = forge.pki.rsa;

var keypair = rsa.generateKeyPair({bits: 2048, e: 0x10001});
var pubKeyPEM = pki.publicKeyToPem(keypair.publicKey);
var privKeyPEM = pki.privateKeyToPem(keypair.privateKey);
console.log(pubKeyPEM);
console.log(privKeyPEM);
```

The `forge.pki.rsa.setPublicKey`-method is used to generate a public key *via modulus and exponent*, where the modulus is the first parameter and the exponent is the second parameter ([[2]](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/master/lib/rsa.js)), both of type `forge.jsbn.BigInteger` ([[3]](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/master/lib/jsbn.js)):

```
var BigInteger = forge.jsbn.BigInteger;
var n = new BigInteger('c7c5dd235568711a943ebbdacac890ca2cf12c1ab539f77726e8874d2ab4220cf06369358b5eff0425fb17d4f696f741cf04c5ea874415e7f67d118a2e763e641e8675b8f42e9277b3f70f14e4de23fe16f51abdc427490f47e4b28ae3e5eb3563ba797fe90f9b70ba878646b1b297c52ba735827682b67309d38b423e31b50b', 16);
var e = new BigInteger('10001', 16);
var pubKey = rsa.setPublicKey(n, e);

var pubKeyPEM = pki.publicKeyToPem(pubKey)
console.log(pubKeyPEM); // Check with e.g. https://lapo.it/asn1js/
```